# Does Fourier Algebra of locally compact group separate compact sets of the group?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. Consider the left regular representation $\lambda$ over $L^2(G)$. Then according to Eymard, Fourier algebra of $G$, $A(G)$ is the set of all coefficients of $\lambda$, i.e. $A(G) = \{\lambda_{x,y} : x,y \in L^2(G)\}$  where, $\lambda_{x,y}(g) = \langle \lambda(g)x,y\rangle$. From the definition of $\lambda$, we have $A(G) \subset C(G,\Bbb{C})$. Since $G$ is completely regular, we can separate disjoint compact sets with continuous functions. Does $A(G)$ separate disjoint compact sets too?

---

EDIT by YC: this question has also been posed at MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745237/does-fourier-algebra-of-locally-compact-group-separate-compact-sets-of-the-group

Comment: For disjoint compact sets $A$ and $B$ in $G$ you can find an open $U$ containing $A$ and an identity nbd $V$ s.t $VU^{-1}$ is disjoint from $A$. You can find continuous functions $\phi,\psi$ supported on $U,V$ and equal 1 on $A,e$ correspondingly. The corresponding matrix coef will separate $A$ and $B$. I don't think this is a research level question.

Comment: @user89334 i.e., $\lambda_{\phi,\psi}$ separate $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Yes (possibly I was careless with the choice of $U$ and $V$ but I think I spelled it correctly, otherwise a little modification will do it, and this should be an easy exercise).

Comment: I'm removing the amenability tag which does not seem relevant

Comment: Comment to my first comment: it appears that the third instance of $A$ should be replaced by $B$.

Comment: @user89334 Also, I think it should be $U^{-1}V$

Comment: Mambo, as long as you agree that this is overall not so hard, I'm happy.

Comment: @user89334  I am reading amenability. There is a theorem by Leptin where he characterizes the amenability of the group by the Fourier algebras having bounded approximate identity. He uses that $A(G)$ is regular. I understand that it is not research level question. Maybe the way the posted the question led you think so

Comment: Dear Mambo, I apologize for the tone of my first comment. I am rather new to this site myself, and I still need some tuning. Your question seemed very basic to me and I suppose that it suits better at MSE, but I truly don't know - I am not a user of MSE. I guess that the number of up-votes is with some correlation with questions quality, but I have to admit that I was surprised often of how bad this correlation is, in both ways.

Comment: @user89334 No problem. I posted this at MSE. I didn't get any response.

Comment: For next time, indicate this in the question's body. You'd get a more simpathic atitude. I will upvote and also go foreward and post my comment as an answer then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38822/discussion-between-mambo-and-user89334).

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect that this result (with essentially the same proof given by @user89334 ) should be in the original paper of Eymard which introduces the Fourier algebra

Comment: @YemonChoi But the paper is available only in French !

Comment: @Mambo I sympathise, but it is worth learning enough mathematical French to read some of the papers of people like Godement, Eymard, Dixmier

Comment: @YemonChoi I would also like to read Godement's paper. Fortunately, Diximier's book is available in English. My Professor always speaks about these three people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disjoint compact sets $A$ and $B$ in $G$ you can find an open set $U$ containing $A$ and an identity nbd $V$ such that both have compact closures and $UV^{−1}$ is disjoint from $B$. You can find $[0,1]$-valued continuous functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ supported on $U$ and $V$ correspondingly such that $\phi|_A=1$ and $\psi(e)=1$. Then it is easy to check that the matrix coefficient $\lambda_{\psi,\phi}$ is zero on $B$ but poisitive on $A$.
I will not spell out the computation, only note that you use the regularity of the Haar measure and continuity when you prove positivity.

Comment: Good luck in your search of $U,V$ when $B = A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Guntram, for pointing the typo so kindly. Fixed.